# playing audio files sequentially does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, audio

In an English/Thai language web page, I've got 4 columns of English phrases with associated audio files. A phrase from each column is selected by mouse click. After 4 phrases have been selected, I want their audio files to play sequentially. Here is 1 of 4 segments of code doing the selection (they differ only in html tags selection and localStorage locations).These work OK.

```
var audioIsPlaying = false;

jQuery("div#wh_set1").on("click", "p span", function (evnt) {      
  var elementId = evnt.target.id,
  word1 = jQuery(this).text();
  jQuery("span#word1").html(word1);                
    var pathVar = document.getElementById("pathVar").innerHTML,
       oggVar = pathVar+elementId+".ogg",
       mp3Var = pathVar+elementId+".mp3";
       if(Modernizr.audio.ogg) {
         localStorage.setItem("wh_set1", oggVar);
      }else {
        localStorage.setItem("wh_set1", mp3Var);
    }
 });
```

Sequential playback of the audio files is intended to be handled by the following code:

```
var currentAudio  = document.createElement('audio'),  i ;  
function audioPlay(i)  {
  audioIsPlaying = false;
  currentAudio.setAttribute("src", localStorage.getItem('wh_set' + i));
  currentAudio.load();
  currentAudio.play();
  audioIsPlaying = true;
//    alert("wh_set" +i);                                                        
}
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  currentAudio.addEventListener("ended", audioPlay(i));
}
```

But this does not work as intended. Only the audio file of the last of the 4 selected phrases plays. If the alert is uncommented then each selection plays in the correct sequence. Similarly, if the code is stepped thru with Firebug, then the audio files play in correct sequence. 
I've had a look at previous posts on audio file sequencing but I could see anything directly applicable.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: you don't add function to event ended, you call it immediatly.
Your code do this:

```
audioPlay(1);
audioPlay(2);
audioPlay(3);
audioPlay(4);
```

The first three audios don't have a chance to load and start.

I replaced

```
for(i = 1; i <= 4; i++) {
  currentAudio.addEventListener("ended", audioPlay(i));
}
```

to

```
 var i = 1;
    currentAudio.addEventListener( "ended", function() {
      i++;
      if ( i < 5 ) {
        audioPlay( i );
      }
    } );
  audioPlay( 1 );
```

and it works perfectly in Chrome and Firefox

Comment: Hi Vassily, as you say it works perfectly. That's great, thanks very much.

Comment: a small mod. audioPlay(1) to audioPlay(i)